# Appending variable dynamically to this property

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to pass the `item` variable dynamic into this property e.g. If the item has value of `35` it will become `this.BookingConfirmationFormsState35`

```
onChange( event, item ){
   console.log( this.BookingConfirmationFormsState+item ); // Doesn't work
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use bracket notation `[]` to access the dynamic property name:

```
this['BookingConfirmationFormsState' + item];
```

For `item = 35`, the above code is equivalent to:

```
this.BookingConfirmationFormsState35
```

Answer (score 1):

```
onChange( event, item ){
   console.log( this['BookingConfirmationFormsState' + item]);
}
```